# How to create the GtkListview by Glade3?

Tags: gtk3, glade

I'm using glade3 to develop a simple app on windows. The official reference manual seems out of date, so I use the gtk-function to create the Listview and put the MySQL-Query result under the field rows. Need help about create the listview by glade3 not by the codes.

Thanks anymore!
My code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "mysql.h"

#define HOST "localhost"
#define USERNAME "root"
#define PASSWORD ""
#define DATABASE "student"

enum ListCols
{
    LIST_NUM,
    LIST_NAME,
    LIST_CHECKED,
    LIST_CNT
};

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkWidget* win;
    GtkWidget* vbox ;
    GtkWidget* statusbar ;
    GtkTreeView* tree;
    GtkTreeView* list;
    GtkTreeStore* tree_store;
    GtkListStore*  list_store;
    GtkTreeIter iter;
    GtkTreeIter iter_child;
    GtkCellRenderer* renderer;
    GtkTreeViewColumn* column;
    GtkTreeSelection* select;

    MYSQL my_connection;
    MYSQL_RES *res_ptr;
    MYSQL_FIELD *field;
    MYSQL_ROW result_row;

    int res;
    int row, col;
    int i, j;
    char * sql = "select * from person;";

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
    win = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (win), "QueryData");
    gtk_window_set_position (GTK_WINDOW (win), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(win, 480, 480);

    vbox = gtk_vbox_new (FALSE, 2);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (win), vbox);

    list = gtk_tree_view_new();
    list_store = gtk_list_store_new(LIST_CNT,
                                    G_TYPE_STRING, 
                                    G_TYPE_STRING, 
                                    G_TYPE_BOOLEAN);

    mysql_init(&my_connection);
    if (mysql_real_connect(&my_connection, HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD,DATABASE, 0, NULL, CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS))
    {
        printf("Query data successfully!\n");
        mysql_query(&my_connection, "set names utf8");

        res = mysql_query(&my_connection, sql);
        if (res)
        {
            printf("Error： mysql_query !\n");
            mysql_close(&my_connection);
        }
        else
        {
            res_ptr = mysql_store_result(&my_connection);
            if (res_ptr)
            {
                col = mysql_num_fields(res_ptr);
                row = mysql_num_rows(res_ptr) + 1;

                printf("%d lines queried\n", row);
                for (i = 0; field = mysql_fetch_field(res_ptr); i++)
                    printf("%s ", field->name);
                printf("\n");

                for (i = 1; i < row; i++)
                {
                    result_row = mysql_fetch_row(res_ptr);
                    gtk_list_store_append(list_store, &iter);
                    gtk_list_store_set(list_store, &iter,
                                       LIST_NUM, result_row[0],
                                       LIST_NAME, result_row[2],
                                       LIST_CHECKED, FALSE, -1);
                }
            }
            mysql_close(&my_connection);
        }
    }
    else
        printf("Fail to query data!\n");
    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)


    gtk_tree_view_set_model(list, list_store);
    g_object_unref(list_store);

    renderer = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new();
    column = gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes("Name", renderer,
             "text", LIST_NUM, NULL);
    column = gtk_tree_view_append_column(list, column);
    renderer = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new();
    column = gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes("Age", renderer,
             "text", LIST_NAME, NULL);
    column = gtk_tree_view_append_column(list, column);
    renderer = gtk_cell_renderer_toggle_new();
    column = gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes("PersonInfo", renderer,
             "active", LIST_CHECKED, NULL);
    column = gtk_tree_view_append_column(list, column);
    gtk_box_pack_start(vbox, list, TRUE, TRUE, 1);

    g_signal_connect (win, "destroy", gtk_main_quit, NULL);

    gtk_widget_show_all (win);
    gtk_main ();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you have to create a container to hold the treeview. If your using a grid, you can use a ScrolledWindow for example. In this example I just put it directly in the window container. Drag the TreeView on the window container:

[image]

Then a dialog asks you for the corresponding treestore:

[image]

Press on the pen and paper icon to open another dialog. Then press on "new".

[image]

This will get you back to the first dialog, with the newly created TreeStore already filled into the field. You can just press "Create":

[image]

Then you can start creating columns for the TreeStore. I created on for the Name (gchararray) and one for the Age (gint):

[image]

After that you can add data to the TreeStore:

[image]

Finally you still have to add columns to the TreeView. That is done by clicking on the TreeView --> click edit --> go to Hierarchy tab --> Add as many columns as you need.

[image]

Don't forget to also load the liststore from the Glade file, otherwise your data will not be present, when you run the program from the code.

Comment: @raphael008 - On stackoverflow you can also upvote and accept helpful answers.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you already have a container and you want to add a tree view into it.

To do that, you look at the "Control and Display" category of widgets, and locate "tree view". If you can't find it, or can't identify the icon, try hovering each icon until you find it.

Click on the icon, then click on the container that you wish to add it to. This will immediately cause a dialog box to occur, asking you to link it with a tree model. You can click the pencil icon, then click "New" to create a list store.

Alternatively, you can create a list store or tree store first. In the widget selection side panel, look under "Miscellaneous". (Between "Composite Widgets" and "Deprecated".) Locate list store or tree store, and click on it to create it. Now if you create the tree view (using the method above), you can choose this tree store / list store as your model.